# Replace "&" with &amp; in body

Tags: javascript, html

Line 251, Column 117: character "&" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data.

```
…elf" href="/service/el-amp-sikring/">El & Sikring<!--<span>›</span>--></a></li>
```

Is there anyway that I can replace all "&" signs within the body, because these are given from the backend. So it is the & that is placed in the html?

*EDIT
Im trying to validate my webpage, and there keep occurring errors and warnings about this "&" symbol in both javascript, html and so on, but ofc i dont wanna change my "&" symbols in the javascript, so what i try to attempt is to change every "&" symbol given by the frontend using umbraco v 4.7.1.1

*EDIT2

```
<ul id="nav">
<% foreach (var topItem in Content.CurrentLanguage.VisibleChildren) { %>
<% var topMenuItems = NodeLocator.GetNodeOfExactType<TopMenuItems>(topItem.Id); %>
<li class="<%= topMenuItems != null ? "hasDropdown" : "" %><%= NodeController.IsNodeDescendantOfNode(Content.Id, topItem.Id) ? " active" : "" %>">
    <a href="<%= topItem.Url %>"><%= topItem.MenuTitle %></a>
    <%  if (topMenuItems != null) { %>
    <div class="drop">
        <div class="drop-holder">
            <div class="drop-frame">
                <div class="drop-content">
                    <div class="col-a">
                        <%= string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(topMenuItems.LeftHeading) ? "" : "<strong>{0}</strong>".With(topMenuItems.LeftHeading) %>
                        <div class="holder">
                            <% foreach (var part in topMenuItems.LeftTargets.Split(1)) { %>
                            <ul>
                                <% foreach (var htmlLink in part) { %>
                                    <li style="" class="" ><a target="_self" href="<%= htmlLink.Url %>"><%= htmlLink.Title %><!--<span>›</span>--></a></li>
                                <% } %>
                                <li style="display:none;"></li>
                            </ul>
                            <% } %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-b">
                        <%= string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(topMenuItems.RightHeading) ? "" : "<strong>{0}</strong>".With(topMenuItems.RightHeading)%>
                        <div class="holder">
                            <% foreach (var part in topMenuItems.RightTargets.Split(2)) { %>
                            <ul>
                                <% foreach (var htmlLink in part) { %>
                                    <li style="" class="" ><a target="_self" href="<%= htmlLink.Url %>"><%= htmlLink.Title %><!--<span>›</span>--></a></li>
                                <% } %>
                                <li style="display:none;"></li>
                            </ul>
                            <% } %>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <% if(topMenuItems.Image != null) { %>
                        <div class="col-c">
                            <div class="holder">
                                <div class="image-holder">
                                    <img src="<%= uComponents.Core.uQuery.GetMedia(topMenuItems.Image.Value).Url() %>" class="superimg" width="214" height="150" alt="superimg" />
                                </div>
                                <a href="<%= topMenuItems.ImageLink.Url %>" class="getoffer"><%= topMenuItems.ImageLink.Title %></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <% } %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% } %>
</li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: You want to perform the string replacement in JavaScript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope: the JavaScript is run too late. By the time the JavaScript is run, the browser has already been forced to parse the ill-formed HTML. You'll need to fix the back-end.

**Update:** In your C#/ASP.NET code, change this:

```
<%= htmlLink.Title %>
```

to this:

```
<%= Server.HtmlEncode(htmlLink.Title) %>
```

in both places.

(See ["HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode Method (String)" in the .NET framework documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz.aspx).)

Comment: This is making the assumption that the HTML is being served as a page, what's to say the HTML isn't coming via an AJAX call?

Comment: so what solution do you recommend that i go for ?

Comment: @SimonPertersen Update your question to be a bit more specific i.e. what exactly is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: @James: Interesting thought! But, even now that you've pointed out the assumption, I'm still quite comfortable with it.

Comment: by the way the site is build in C Sharp.

Comment: @SimonPertersen that's kinda irrelevant based on the question you have asked. How is the HTML being served up? Is it a straight page request? Is it being pulled down via AJAX and then rendered on screen?

Comment: please go check the edit, im pretty new to this problem so i dont really know what you need to know to help me and the community solving the problem. So please give a hint what you need to know.

I have this drop down menu with some links in it, and 2 of them contain "&", this dropdown is generated from the backend using c# which is bound with the .net that give the user of the frontend, the possibility to change the name of the link. 

So how to overwrite all "&" symbols with the "&amp;" so i dont get the errors when i validate

Comment: @SimonPertersen: As I wrote in my answer, you'll need to fix the back-end. The HTML Validator doesn't (and shouldn't) run your JavaScript.

Comment: @ruakh: how to fix it thats kinda what im trying to do by asking here?

Comment: @SimonPertersen: You fix it . . . by fixing it. You have a bug in your C# code, whereby it outputs `&` when it needs to be outputting `&amp;`. You haven't posted any of your C# code, so there's no way anyone here can help you fix it.

Comment: @ruakh: just posted all the code that execute the menu where the error is.

Comment: @SimonPertersen: I've updated my answer to give a fix for the specific place where you're seeing this problem; however, you'll probably want to apply the same fix to all parts of your code where you're outputting an arbitrary string.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regular expression in your IDE, back-end code or javascript to replace all "&"s that are not already followed by "amp;" with "&":

```
str.replace(/&(?!amp;)/g, '&amp;'​)
```

Answer (score -3):

If you need to do javascript, this replaces every & which has a space behind it.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.split("& ").join("&amp; ");
```

Comment: I know, but that's the only thing you can do if you don't have access to the input, plus he doesn't give much more data does he... And it will work correctly ;-) I've tested it. works beautifully.

Comment: The browser should normalize the innerHTML so that it will already have `&amp;`.